# React native TypeError: navigation is undefined

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with navigation in React Native. Navigation works for every component except a few. I have the same error in each of the non-working components.

`TypeError: navigation is undefined`

An example component that does not work

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'

export const EventInfo = ({ navigation }) => {

    const { name, date } = route.params;

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Name: {JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
            <Text>Date: {JSON.stringify(date)}</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

The component from which the information comes

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export const EventCard = ({ navigation, eventName, eventDate }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EventInfo', { name: eventName, date: eventDate })}>
            <Text>{eventName}</Text>
            <Text>{eventDate}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

I'm using the component here

```
<EventCard eventName="Testing test" eventDate="04.08.2021" />
```

Other components only work properly when this problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add navigaton

```
<EventCard eventName="Testing test" navigation={navigation} eventDate="04.08.2021" />
```